# Access Office 365 Library

Tags: api, office365

I'm using Office 365 API Tools for Visual Studio. When I run the following code everything works fine and my documents are returned.

```
    string SPResourceID = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com";
    string SPServiceRoot = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api";
    var authenticator = new Authenticator();
    var result = await authenticator.AuthenticateAsync(SPResourceID, ServiceIdentifierKind.Resource);

    // Create a client proxy:

    this.client = new SharePointClient(new Uri(SPServiceRoot), result.GetAccessToken);
    this.client.Context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
```

However, when I try to access a sub web such as:-

```
string SPResourceID = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/test";
string SPServiceRoot = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/test/_api";
```

I am asked to reauthenticate and then get the error "AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/test/' is not registered for the account". Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can access libraries in a sub web and is it possible to pass in the name of the library rather than relying on it being the default library.

Thanks,

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Your SPResourceID is still https://tenant.sharepoint.com/. 
The resourceId is the ID your Office 365 subscription is registered with in azure ad.